# What to fill in the following gap in a journal's publication system: "The author was supported by ..."

Tags: publications

I have this question, (that could be closed because it is not a problem of mathematics):

I am a PhD student, my first article was accepted by a journal, and for the publication in the web site of the journal , there is some sentences to fill, between these senteces there is this one to fill:

"The author was supported by ......."

what to write here ?

Thanks for any answer and sorry for my english

Comment: Have you asked your advisor?

Comment: Hi and welcome to Academia SE, and congratulations for your first article! Generally, journals allow to specify certain types of grants, but this is really something you should discuss with your advisor.

Comment: @MassimoOrtolano, why not as an answer?

Comment: Note that the question is normally about financial support, not personal or academic support and advice.

Comment: Thank you for all your comments, i have asked  the advisor and he  says that i shoud put the name of my "doctoral school"

Comment: @Buffy I didn't put it as an answer because the phrasing of that sentence is quite different from that of the journals I'm used to.

Answer (score 3):

This question asks what the author's funding is - in the case of PhD students, where the funding for your stipend/research is coming from. If your advisor has a grant that is covering your work, then the agency that issued the funding is the one you acknowledge here. If you have a scholarship, then the agency that issued the scholarship is the one you acknowledge. If you are self-funded, then you can leave it blank, or name your university.

In any case, if you are unsure, ask your advisor.